# Apache doesn't load index.php

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu

I've configured my virtual host which looks like this:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName zf2-tutorial.localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/zf2-tutorial/public
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
<Directory /var/www/html/zf2-tutorial/public>
     DirectoryIndex index.php
     AllowOverride All
     Order allow,deny
     Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

But instead of running index.php Apache loads a page with folders. I can navigate to zf2-tutorial.localhost/zf2-tutorial/public/ explicitly and it loads correctly.

I've tried:

disabling mod_autoindex by running `sudo a2dismod autoindex`

adding Options -Indexes inside virtual host configuration file.

checking dir.conf in mods-available folder(which seems to be fine).

Nothing.

P.S.

Also, this whole Apache configuration confuses me. Since I'm running this on Ubuntu, /etc/apache2/ has only apache2.conf. httpd.conf is in /usr/local/apache2/conf/. So if I modify httpd.conf I gotta restart the process by issuing a `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart`. Right? Then what is this `sudo /usr/local/apache2/bin/apachectl -k restart` command for?

Comment: maybe you've got another vhost definition that's "catching" before apache reaches the one you've posted above.

Comment: Not sure what `sudo /usr/local/apache2/bin/apachectl -k restart` is for. As an Ubuntu user for almost a year I have never used that. But you should only edit configurations in */etc/apache2*. did you also change the config in the *sites-available* directory?

Comment: @samrap I did. Still it doesn't work.

Comment: and you didn't change anything in `/usr/local/apache2/conf/`?

Comment: @samrap Indeed I did change a few things. I rolled back the httpd.conf file to its original state, and the problem has solved itself. Anyway thank you to all who commented.

Comment: @Linas close the question then.